HTML Media Capture and Android saving photos to gallery
There are older reports of Android devices saving photos to the gallery when using HTML Media Capture. Does anyone know if this is still an issue? I want to use html media capture without photos being stored to the users device.
Thread

Prevent auto-saving of photos to gallery when uploading photos in Android Browser using input type=file capture=camera

I cannot replicate the problem on newer Android devices using the latest HTML capture specs. Example code:
<input type="file" id="picture" name="picture" accept="image/*" capture="environment" />
